# K-means on Mahout returning non-exclusive clusters

Tags: cluster-analysis, k-means, mahout

In my data I have users with a list of likes, I've dumped these likes into individual files for each user and would like to cluster them.  Everything is working except the output has the same likes in multiple clusters.  My understanding is k-means should be exclusive.  I figure the problem is perhaps with how I am dumping the data.  I have also dumped all of the likes without spaces for the time being until I can write a custom tokenizer.  Here's what I'm running (from a ruby script).

```
system("#{MAHOUT_CMD} seqdirectory -c UTF-8 -i data/users -o data/kmeans/converted")
system("#{MAHOUT_CMD} seq2sparse -i data/kmeans/converted -o data/kmeans/vectors")
system("#{MAHOUT_CMD} kmeans -i data/kmeans/vectors/tfidf-vectors -c data/kmeans/initial_clusters -o data/kmeans/kmeans_clusters -dm org.apache.mahout.common.distance.EuclideanDistanceMeasure -cd 0.1 -k 20 -x 20")

last_cluster_folder = Dir["data/kmeans/kmeans_clusters/*"].last.gsub("data/kmeans/kmeans_clusters/", "")

system("#{MAHOUT_CMD} clusterdump -s data/kmeans/kmeans_clusters/#{last_cluster_folder}/ -d data/kmeans/vectors/dictionary.file-0 -dt sequencefile -o data/kmeans/clusters.txt -n 1000")
```

The output lists the "top terms" in each cluster, however many of the likes occur in each cluster (though with different weights).  Is the normal output for clusterdumper, do I need to find out what cluster each word belongs to by its weight?

Thanks

Comment: This is probably going to be much more successful on user@mahout.apache.org

Answer (score 0):

Mahout probably is only doing *approximate* k-means. Plus, there might be objects that have the same distance to more than one cluster.

You should however be able to just take the `k` means, and then do a 1-nearest-neighbor classification to get a unique result for each objects (this is trivial to parallelize and very fast).